# Well distributed features using Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to find matches between two frames of a video sequence (no big movement just a step), I used SURF and FAST features along with brute force matcher, results are good but what I need is to get "well" distributed features, I looked up and found that there is something called [Adaptive non-maximal suppression](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs4243/lecture/feature.pdf) in Szeliski book that does exactly, so is there any thing that does that in opencv, and I want the matcher to look for matches in a small window no need to scan all descriptors.

Comment: More suitable to dsp.stackexchange

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Matlab has a built-in [`selectUniform`](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/vision/ref/kazepoints.selectuniform.html) function that can do similar results, while taking into account a uniform distribution of spatial locations and local reponse maximisation. It is recommended that you use C/C++ code generation in order to use it with opencv in C++.

Answer (score 3):

There is a recent paper ["Efficient adaptive non-maximal suppression algorithms for homogeneous spatial keypoint distribution"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323388062_Efficient_adaptive_non-maximal_suppression_algorithms_for_homogeneous_spatial_keypoint_distribution) that tackles the problem of homogeneous keypoint distribution on the image. C++, Python, and Matlab interfaces are provided in this [repository](https://github.com/BAILOOL/ANMS-Codes). It can be effortlessly included to your c++ code and work with keypoints derived with OpenCV.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple python implementation I wrote for KD-Tree based local Non-Maximum suppression of features. It assumes kps is an array of opencv 2d sparse features (SIFT, SURF, AKAZE, etc...). 
It sorts the features based on (descending) score, then start querying them in score order, removing neighbors of high score features from the set (and avoiding their future querying for efficiency)

Tweak r to the spatial sparsity that you want and k_max depending on initial density of features.

```
from scipy.spatial.kdtree import KDTree
import numpy as np

def KDT_NMS(kps, descs=None, r=15, k_max=20):
    """ Use kd-tree to perform local non-maximum suppression of key-points
    kps - key points obtained by one of openCVs 2d features detectors (SIFT, SURF, AKAZE etc..)
    r - the radius of points to query for removal
    k_max - maximum points retreived in single query
    """
    # sort by score to keep highest score features in each locality
    neg_responses = [-kp.response for kp in kps]
    order = np.argsort(neg_responses)
    kps = np.array(kps)[order].tolist()

    # create kd-tree for quick NN queries
    data = np.array([list(kp.pt) for kp in kps])
    kd_tree = KDTree(data)

    # perform NMS using kd-tree, by querying points by score order, 
    # and removing neighbors from future queries
    N = len(kps)
    removed = set()
    for i in range(N):
        if i in removed:
            continue

        dist, inds = kd_tree.query(data[i,:],k=k_max,distance_upper_bound=r)
        for j in inds: 
            if j>i:
                removed.add(j)

    kp_filtered = [kp for i,kp in enumerate(kps) if i not in removed]
    descs_filtered = None
    if descs is not None:
        descs = descs[order]
        descs_filtered = np.array([desc for i,desc in enumerate(descs) if i not in removed],dtype=np.float32)
    print('Filtered',len(kp_filtered),'of',N)
    return kp_filtered, descs_filtered
```